# does exist a Dart plugin for Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, dart, netbeans-8

The only information about creating a dart plugin from netbeans is this one:

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/dart_and_netbeans_ide_7

Was this plugin ever created?

where is the Soruce Code?

Is there any other plan to integrate Dart to Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of a Dart plugin for NetBeans but it seems there was an attempt
- https://plus.google.com/+netbeans/posts/6pxRJwpZ3rJ
- https://www.java.net/story/geertjan-wielenga-dart-and-netbeans-ide-74
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/dart_and_netbeans_ide_7